# Gradle is ignoring one of my Spock unit tests and it doesn't tell me why

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, spock

I have a Spock unit test (specification) with 3 tests defined.  Two of the tests execute fine, but one of them is ignored completely by Spock or Gradle and I can't figure out why.

Here's the ignored test:

```
    def "connect to kinesis"() {

        given:

        Yaml parser = new Yaml()
        YAMLConfig config = parser.load((testConfigFileName as File).text)

        putKinesisRecordsUtil.config = config

        putKinesisRecordsUtil.putRecords(mockKinesisClient)

        1 * mockKinesisClient.putRecords(_)

        expect:

        1 == 1

    }
```

The presence of one line in this test that determines if the test is ignored:

```
putKinesisRecordsUtil.config = config
```

That's it.  Why would specifying a parameter in putKinesisRecordsUtil make Spock or Gradle ignore the entire test without a warning or error message?  Am I populating this value correctly?

The test extends `spock.lang.Specification` and the other tests run successfully.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does your test class extend `spock.lang.Specification`?

Comment: Yes, my test extends ```spock.lang.Specification```.  The other two tests are able to run successfully.

Comment: Have you tried adding a try catch around the problematic line? I know you would expect any exception to result in a failed feature and not an ignored one, but might be worth double checking.

Comment: I suggest you post a link to a GitHub repository that reproduces the issue. We'd have to see more configuration to see how your test and build code is structured.

Comment: Benjamin is right, we need to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If this one line you mentioned is causing problems, without the variable definition and underlying class is is next to impossible to tell you the problem's root cause. People on SO like to analyse problems, not guess wildly.

Answer (score 0):

Interactions should be placed within a "then" block or anywhere before the "when" block.  I've refactored your test to use "given", "when", and "then".  Then moved the interaction to the then block.

[Where to put interactions](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions)

> As a guideline, use when-then to describe methods with side effects, and expect to describe purely functional methods.

[Spock Framework Reference Documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_blocks)

```
def "connect to kinesis"() {
    given:
    Yaml parser = new Yaml()

    when:
    YAMLConfig config = parser.load((testConfigFileName as File).text)
    putKinesisRecordsUtil.config = config
    putKinesisRecordsUtil.putRecords(mockKinesisClient)

    then:
    1 * mockKinesisClient.putRecords(_)
    1 == 1
}
```

Hope this helps!